# Intellij startup error: IDE has not been initialized yet

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I updated to Intellij Community Edition 2020.1.2 and after installtion, it is not starting. I ran the idea.bat file from command prompt and get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin>idea.bat
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
IDE has not been initialized yet
```

My java home is set to Jdk 10

Can someone please help??

Thanks!

Comment: Use a download with an embedded jvm

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: try https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

Answer (score 5):

Try checking you have no other instance of IDEA running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it takes a really long time to start up without any indication that it is running. You'll get that error message printed when you try to start the application a second time, while the first instance is still starting. Check the Task Manager and you should see that IntelliJ is running.